# Can't connect to the database with my class?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect to my database but it won't connect. I tried but won't connect. the error I'm getting is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'connect' (T_STRING) in C:\htdocs\www\dating\index.php on line 3. I called the tried new Database connect(); and tried connect(); I get this message Fatal error: Call to undefined function connect() in C:\htdocs\www\dating\index.php on line 3. What's wrong?

```
class Database{
private $db_host = "localhost";
private $db_user = "123346";
private $db_pass = "12345";
private $db_name =  "1234";
public  $conn;
// Create connection
public function connect(){
    if(!isset($this->conn)){
        $this->conn = new mysqli_connect($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->pass,$this->db_name);

        if($this->conn){
            $this->conn = true;
            return true;
        }else{
            $this->conn = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
public function disconnect(){
    if(isset($this->conn)){
        if(mysqli_close($this->conn)){
            $this->myconn = false; 
            echo "connection closed";
            return true; 
        } else{
            echo "failed to close connection";
            return false; 
            }
        }else{
        echo "no connection prescent";
        }
    }

}
```

I'm trying to get use query now but it won't get the results. Here is the code

```
 include("functions/connect.php");
 $db = new Database("localhost", "12345", "1234", "123");
 $db->connectdb();
 $db->select('rpg');


/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$query = "SELECT id, username FROM users ORDER by ID DESC ";



if ($result = $db->query($query)) {

/* fetch object array */
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
}

/* free result set */
$result->close();
}
 /* close connection */
$db->close();`
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change this line

```
$this->conn = new mysqli_connect($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->pass,$this->db_name);
```

to this

```
$this->conn = new mysqli_connect($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass,$this->db_name);
```

You will notice you used `$this->pass` but it should be `$this->db_pass`.

---

To call the function of Database class you have to write your code like this;

```
<?php
include("functions/connect.php");

$db_conn = new Database();
if($db_conn->connect()) {
  echo "Database connected";
}
```

Comment: I did and still getting the same error's Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'connect' (T_STRING) in C:\htdocs\www\dating\index.php on line 3 and Fatal error: Call to undefined function connect() in C:\htdocs\www\dating\index.php on line 3

Comment: Will you please write here your code, how are you calling the connect() function of Database class?

Comment: `<?php 
          include("functions/connect.php");
 $db = new Database ($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
?>`

Comment: Thank's @JazyK i found out that I wasn't using `$db->connect();` function all the long. Your code helped to with the wrong db_pass.